# Navigating inside an intercepted route nextjs 13.4.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm building a project where when a user clicks a link in one of my tables they should be redirected into a modal containing information connected to the object they clicked on. Inside the modal they should be able to navigate between different pages without dismissing it.  I'm using the intercepting technique from their [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes) and everything is working so far. However, when the user reloads the page and gets redirected to the actual page that I previously intercepted and they try to navigate, it opens the modal on top of the same page as they're on.

Ex:
User clicks on a link in a table => modal opens (aka intercepting the route) => user reloads the page and ends up on the actual routed page => user navigates still inside the same layout => even though the user is on the "actual" routed page NextJS intercepts the route again and opens a modal containing the same content.

Is there any way to tell Next not to intercept certain links?